# google cloud functions default environment variables not set

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions

Are there any conditions to the default environment variables being set on google cloud function?

I have the following code:

```golang
func init() {
    projectID := os.Getenv("GCP_PROJECT")
    log.Printf("projectID: %s\n", projectID)

    functionName := os.Getenv("FUNCTION_NAME")
    log.Printf("functoinName: %s\n", functionName)

    region := os.Getenv("FUNCTION_REGION")
    log.Printf("region: %s\n", region)
}
```

and the values are empty.

Even if I do:

```golang
func GameUpdate(ctx context.Context, e FirestoreEvent) error {
    functionName := os.Getenv("FUNCTION_NAME")
    log.Printf("functoinName: %s\n", functionName)
}
```

They are still empty.

According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var), I would expect them to be set and available. But they are not :|

### EDIT:

I am using go 1.13 as runtime and as [Armatorix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62075003/1432239) mentioned, these env variables are not available in that runtime...

Why I needed them was to write a wrapper for `cloud.google.com/go/logging`  to be able to tag the severity of the logs.

I ended up prepending my stdout logs with `[INFO]`/`[ERROR]`, and creating a tag from it `\[([A-Z]+)\].*`. Bonus is that I don't have to do a network call in my function to ship the logs.

Still disappointing that these environment variables are not available.

Answer (score 4):

So I've read the same documentation.
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#nodejs_6_nodejs_8_python_37_and_go_111) you've got the info that it works like this with go1.11 (And it works, I tested it out).
BUT for go1.13 these are not set. You can still do it manually.
Also I've checked which envs are set on 1.13 version.

From os.Envrion()

```
PATH=/layers/google.go.build/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
FUNCTION_SIGNATURE_TYPE=http
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
HOME=/root
K_REVISION=9
FUNCTION_TARGET=HelloWorld
PORT=8080
GOROOT=/usr/local/go/
CGO_ENABLED=1
PWD=/srv
K_SERVICE=function-1
```

So the env that you probably want to use is `K_SERVICE`

Comment: Interesting. I however need `FUNCTION_REGION` and `GCP_PROJECT` as well, which don't seem to be available.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/157719049) on your behalf, in order for Cloud Functions Engineering team to implement the automatic set of these Environment Variables to the newer Runtime Versions, such as Node.js 10 and Go1.13.

You may "star" the issue so that it gets visibility and also include yourself in the "CC" section, in order to receive further updates posted on this thread.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Thanks :bow:.

Answer (score 0):

I created a library for that very purpose:
[github.com/ncruces/go-gcf/logging](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ncruces/go-gcf/logging)

But you're right, on the Go 1.13 runtime, those environment variables are missing. On the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/migrating/nodejs-runtimes) they suggest setting them when you deploy.

Later I found that the recommended way of doing this is to use [structured logging](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#writing_logs).

```
// Structured logging can be used to set severity levels.
// See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging.
fmt.Println(`{"message": "This has ERROR severity", "severity": "error"}`)
```

So now, I'm in the process of "deprecating" my library, and creating a new one, with a simpler approach:
[github.com/ncruces/go-gcp/glog](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ncruces/go-gcp/glog)

This is simple enough that a library isn't really required, but it helps to correctly JSON escape message.

Comment: I tried with structured logging, but in the log viewer they just pop up as plain text payload. and the severity is set to "default".

Comment: I have it deployed and working with my `glog` library, which uses structured logging. If you have the time, try it and then debug why it wasn't working for you.

Comment: I took a quick look at the code for your library. Could this be the reason that stackdriver detects it as jsonPayload: `json.NewEncoder(f).Encode(entry{msg, s})`?

Comment: For structured logging to work, you need to output a single, valid, JSON object per line. The best description I've found of the format is from the Cloud Run docs: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#using-json

Comment: More detail [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#process-payload). There's some plugin, that detects JSON, and some fields behave specially.

Anyway, my `glog` library is working for me on both Cloud Functions and Cloud Run. Feel free to use!

Comment: :thinking:, that is what I was doing (for formatting purpose pasted here): https://play.golang.org/p/-X1dvCkP_L3

Comment: Package `log` by default prepends a timestamp into each log line. That means it's not valid JSON. If you want to use `log` instead of `fmt`, you need to do `log.SetFlags(0)` somewhere. See: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/7d0196c13ba00138822b3c405f5efa5d4ca7a1b1/run/logging-manual/main.go#L82

Comment: But again, I would strongly advise against doing either `log` or `fmt` directly. If the `err` you print with `%v` contains any special characters (like `"`) it's no longer valid JSON. You really should be encoding what you print into JSON, and that's best done in a library (mine or any other).